# Getting the state of a commit, and reapplying it in another

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-commit

Setup:

```
----- master branch 
                   \
                    \
                     sprint branch
                                  \
                                   my branch --> commit a --> commit b
```

How can a commit c be created with the changes before a was pushed (both a and b are already pushed)?

(a and b are trial and error commits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git, commits don't "belong to" branches; instead, branches are just a *pointer to a commit*. Commits contain a snapshot of the repository, and zero or more (usually one) parent pointers, from which history can be read backwards.

So if I understand you correctly, you probably don't want to create a *commit*, you just want to create a *branch* (a named pointer) to carry on working on top of an existing commit.

You can do that with the `git branch` command, as long as you know the *commit hash* you want it to point at. You can find that by running `git log`.